# PHP handle download request when session is expired

Tags: php, apache, redirect, download

I'm looking for some help in how best to handle page navigation/redirection from a PHP application.  We don't offer many downloads so this has only just now come up as an issue.  The gist is that a user loads a webpage to view some data and this page offers a hyperlink to download the data into a spreadsheet (dynamically built).  The issue that I'm struggling to come up with a slick solution to is if the user sits on the webpage for long enough to where their session expires in PHP.  Suppose in that case the user comes back to the page and clicks the download link.

There are two scenarios I need to handle.  The first is with old browsers like IE (have to support it for the time being).  IE doesn't support the [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) for ANCHOR elements.  Therefore, when the link is clicked and the session is invalid, the user is presented with a login form but the browser URL now reflects the endpoint of the download.  Upon logging in, the download functions correctly but the user is left at the login form because the presence of the `Content-Type: attachment` makes the browser not navigate. I am looking for how to best get the user back to what is essentially the initial HTTP_REFERER when the download was requested.  The only idea I can come up with is either a standard endpoint or query string parameter to use so that my login form handling code can properly redirect after successful login for a download request.

The other scenario is for modern browsers that support the [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download).  My code does set the HTTP response code to 401 when it determines the login form needs to be rendered (maybe that's not correct though). I do not see anything within $_SERVER that alludes to that fact though which suggests, again, a standard endpoint or query string parameter to use for identification.  Modern browsers handle this case well by simply denying the download and actually displays that the request needs authorization.  So, this works well as long as setting the status to 401 on all login form renders is correct otherwise, I'd again need some way to know that the requested endpoint is a download.

I'd like to avoid any kind of JavaScript solution if possible.

Comment: Should the user be logged out.  You can usually prevent this from happening by sending a simple ajax call every couple minutes that just accesses their session on the backend.  Basically it acts like a heartbeat.  Number two, do you realize you can download a file through an Iframe just by setting the SRC to the download page.  This happens without the user leaving the page or the need for reload.  Typically you make the Iframe very small and hide it with display none or position it offscreen. then trigger it with a link and JS

Comment: Although I respect that you need to support IE for the time being, because you are dealing with an edge case already, is IE minimal enough that you have multiple edge cases that are very, very rare when combined? Someone using IE AND they sit on a page long enough for it to timeout AND they choose to click a download?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix using a "heartbeat" does not seem like an acceptable solution to me and completely invalidates the usage of authenticating a user and having a session expiration.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Fair point.  My web application is mainly used in a third-party native application via an embedded IE control.  Thusly, this is not an edge case for me. 
 WebView2 support is available, but I need to fix this problem first.  It's a bit of a ladder of dependencies sadly.  I cannot just move to WebView2 to eliminate this.  But this scenario is a problem because the user has no address bar to speak of in the application.  It is very likely the user won't know what to do should this scenario occur.

Comment: @tczx3, that makes sense for IE. For your main problem, I think your best bet is to then send _everyone_ not directly to the file, but to a download page. I think you can then throw some very simple JS on that page to disable the link after X amount of seconds.

Comment: @tczx3 - that may be but it was a "suggestion". in fact it was more of a question.  If you take it one step further you can also do a login pop up ( that's what I do ) but it can be a bit tricky to access the session without updating the expiration on the session.  In other words typically checking if a user has a session will in effect extend that session.  So if they never expire you never get a logout pop up.  Hope that makes sense